# Electrical usage data logging with wireless data transfer

Tags: energy, electricity, energy-efficiency, energy-use, energy-management

Does anyone know of a wireless energy usage capture device, that one can attach to an appliance and find out the energy usage?

I know that there are certain energy monitors that do the job to some extent, however I am looking for a small device/tag that can permanently be attached to an appliance or cable to find out energy usage over longer periods of time. Energy monitors can only be attached to a device at a time and display the usage on a monitor, however I am looking for something that can capture and transfer data wirelessly.

I'm researching into a business idea for which this would be very useful.

Comment: Am I missing something here? If you want to measure power consumption you will have to attach it to the power line. For most appliances there is no way to do so. Given that, the easiest way is to plug in into the wall power socket. Which leaves you only with the question "What power monitor can transmits its data wirelessly?". And I assume you mean over Wifi specifically? That is the most compatible wireless protocol nowadays.

Comment: Or are you thinking about something that measures by induction? In that case, what precision do you want? Because attaching it to *any* device and expecting reliable measurements seems impossible. Only if you wrapped it around the power cord you would have approximate equal dimensions (measuring distance) each time, but you have no way of knowing how much that cord is shielded.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like the [Kill A Watt wireless](http://p3international.com/products/p4200.html) might be what you are after. For more alternatives keep reading.

There is another product line called the [Watts-Up](https://www.wattsupmeters.com/secure/products.php?pn=0) that has USB connections to computers on some models, and a built in web server on the high end one. The high end one can be made to work over wireless with an adapter. The USB only versions could be used together with a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) and a USB WIFI adapter to achieve sending the data over the network.

If you are handy with electronics and such you might want to have a look at this [HACKADAY](http://hackaday.com/2014/10/21/digital-data-from-a-cheap-power-meter/) solution. This likewise should interface easily to a [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) or [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) and allow you to send the data over a wireless network.